# Yet another "Is this a pattern and if yes, what's the name"?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, refactoring

> Create an instance from another one of different kind/class.

Quick example: you are using an ORM and you store an email queue in your database. Then at some point you have to send bulk emails, using third party library.

Your object (PHP irrelevant here, public properties for simplicity):

```php
class Mail
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $senderText;

    /**
     * @var My\App\Entity\User
     */
    public $user;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\ArrayCollection
     */
    public $attachments;
}
```

... while your third party "mail" object is far different. For example, you may need to do something like:

```php
$mail = /* hydrated */;
$user = $mail->getUser();

$mailer = new ThirdPartyMailer();

// Fill message properties
$message = $mailer->createMessage();

$fullName = sprintf('%s %s', $user->getFirst(), $user->getLast());
$message->addFrom(array($fullName => $user->getEmail()))

// Create and add attachments
foreach($mail->getAttachments() as $attachment)
{
    $message->attach($mailer->createAttachment($attachment->getFullPath()));
}
```

Is this a pattern? Something like object converter, like a class responsible of creating/converting one instance from another...

Comment: This isn't really a code question; it's a terminology question, and should be on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) instead. Voting to migrate.

Comment: @KenWhite, ok, sorry. I'm voting too. Edit. Can't vote to migrate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of a single widely used name for this pattern, but some common names are "translator" and "converter" -- a class that translates between two different classes representing similar entities.

A related pattern is the [adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern): if the third-party message is exposed as an interface, you could create an adapter class that wraps your existing mail object and implements the third-party interface.

Comment: Yes, that would be nice. Actually (third party) Message implements an interface. But what about setters? Implementing does not make sense to me...

Comment: @Gremo: Are you saying that the Message interface contains setters?

Comment: Yes: https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/master/lib/classes/Swift/Mime/Message.php

Comment: @Gremo: That doesn't seem like a very well designed interface. Interfaces with setters are usually a code smell, and in this case, there is no obvious reason why that interface isn't simply a plain data object. You should probably just use a translator in this case.